# How can I validate Excel columns for NULL prior to loading the data into database?

Tags: ssis

I am validating multiple excel files prior to loading them into a database table.

First, I would like to check for `NULL`, make sure that a threshold criteria of valid number of rows in the file meets **`60%`** mark; if criteria is below **`60%`**, reject the file and send out a mail notification else for 60% and up, process the file, load the data into table and send mail notification. Below is a sample test data for clarity. In this sample data, the following are the validation criteria

1. ID cannot be **`NULL`**, create a new column that flags NULL
2. If `(Non-NULL row count / total row count) < 60%`, then send an error notification and reject file
3. If `(Non-NULL row count / total row count) > 60%`, then move file to final destination and send a success message

#### Sample input file 1:

```
ID    Name
----- ------
1     John
2     Dave
NULL  Jonny
NULL  Kevin
NULL  David
```

This should be rejected because it fails to meet the *`60 percent`* criteria.

```
ID    Name   NULL_Flag Percent
----- ------ --------- -------
1     John       N       40
2     Dave       N       40
NULL  Jonny      Y       40
NULL  Kevin      Y       40
NULL  David      Y       40
```

#### Sample input file 2:

```
ID    Name
----- ------
100   Jack
200   Jill
300   Naomi
400   Tim
```

This file should be processed because it meets the *`60 percent`* criteria and the data should be loaded into destination table.

```
ID    Name   NULL_Flag Percent
----- ------ --------- -------
100   Jack       N      100
200   Jill       N      100
300   Naomi      N      100
400   Tim        N      100
```

How should I approach this problem in SSIS?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each Excel file has the same column layout, I'd build a Data Flow to handle the validation and set a boolean variable to control what to do with any particular file. The precedence constraints linking the Data Flow to the followup tasks would use that boolean variable in expressions:

[image: control flow screenshot]

The data flow would use an Excel source and a Script Transform set as a destination:

[image: data flow screenshot]

The code for the script transfromation, SCR_DST_ValidateFile, would look like this:

```cs
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    private double _nullCount = 0;
    private double _rowCount = 0;
    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        Variables.ValidFile = ((_nullCount / _rowCount) > .6);
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        _rowCount += 1;
        if (Row.ID_IsNull) _nullCount += 1;
    }

}
```

where `ValidFile` is the name of the boolean variable.

**EDIT:** The `SEQ_Valid` and `SEQ_NotValid` Sequence Containers in the control flow above represent whatever components you may need to handle your specific requirements (e.g., sending an email, loading a file's contents into a database, etc.); I used sequence containers just as placeholders.

As for setting up the precedence constraints, the constraint from `DFT_CheckIfSpreadsheetValid` to `SEQ_Valid` is configured thusly:

[image: screenshot of @ValidFile precedence constraint]

while the constraint from `DFT_CheckIfSpreadsheetValid` to `SEQ_NotValid` is configured thusly:

[image: screenshot of !@ValidFile precedence constraint]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed screen shot. I'm trying to incorporate your logic into the package I'm creating. What does the SEQ flow task mean. Is that the sequence container. Also, you mind sharing with you went about setting up your precedence constraints. Thanks